# Schedule to ical

Tags: excel, google-sheets, icalendar

I am issued a schedule each month in the attached format.

I would like to filter my name, and export the data to ical entries for either AM (column B), or PM (column C) shifts.

I can filter my name, but the dates do not follow as they should. HELP!

Comment: We do not see any attachment.

Comment: Excel or Googlesheets? They are not the same…